# Removing last comma in the foreach query in php mysql

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im using a foreach loop to echo out some values from my database and seperating each of them by commas but last comma how we can remove

```
echo $string='"paymentmethods":';
echo $string='"Bank":[';
$sql2 = "SELECT  * FROM paymentmethods where cid=587 ";
$query = $this->db->query($sql2);
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
       echo '{';
       echo $string = 'accname:'.$row->acc.',' ;
       echo $string = 'country:'.$row->IBAN.',' ;
       echo $string = 'Iban:'.$row->Bankname.',' ;
       echo $string = 'Bankname:'.$row->Bankname.',' ;
       echo $string = '},';  
}  
echo $string = '],';

"paymentmethods":"Bank":[{accname:0034430430012,country:AE690240002520511717801,Iban:ARABIC BANK NAME,Bankname:ARABIC BANK NAME,},{accname:0506796049,country:DE690240002520511717801,Iban:ARABIC BANK NAME,Bankname:ARABIC BANK NAME,},]
```

Here see the comma is repeating after the name ends. and also after the end of brackets

Comment: Can we please see it's output and expected output? It's very hard to tell exactly what you are asking!

Comment: To remove the last character from a string, you can easily use substr: `$string = substr($string,0,-1);`

Comment: It seems like you are doing `json_encode` by yourself? Try using the built in `json_encode` to encode the array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: you code it wrong. convert array to json with `json_encode()`

Answer (score 0):

The comma is there because you have written it in your code. Change the lines to this :

```
 // same as above
 echo $string = 'Bankname:'.$row->Bankname. ;
       echo $string = '}';  
}  
echo $string = ']';
```

Answer (score 0):

a common way to do this is to do this way :

```
$sep = '';
$result = '';
foreach($myarray as $value) {
    $result .= $sep.$value;
    $sep = ',';
}
```

this way, you don't have a beginning or ending comma.
But as comments say, you are doing a "json_encode" by yourself... you should use json_encode / decode instead.